# MySQL Join table using a reference

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I need help with MySQL. I am trying to JOIN methods (Left and Inner now)

EDIT: I would also like to INSERT, can someone show me how? Should I use the Trigger? You may show the 2 possible solutions.

I have 4 Tables:

User, Project and User-Project, AssignedProject

```
Table User-Project has 
ID | UserID | ProjectID

Table User has
ID | COMPANYID | UserName |

Table Project has
ID | ProjectName

Table AssignedProject
ID | COMPANYID | ProjectName
```

What I want to do.

I want to join User-Project table with data of User and Project using AssignedProject as my reference table. I don't know if this makes any sense... I will rephrase.

The association of project and user are in the table AssignedProject. However, I want to have the data in User-Project. Though I just need the ID (which are a foreign key in User-Project)

Example:

```
AssignedProject
1 | 1001 | AprojectName

Project
1| AprojectName

User
1 | 1001 | Mike

THEN
User-Project 
1 | 1 | 1
```

Comment: Please show us your expected results for this sample data.

Comment: Why does `AssignedProject` have `ProjectName` instead of a foreign key to `Project.ID`?

Comment: I will show you a sample data. I will need to filter it. Give me a min. Because of how it was designed. I am using MVC so I am building the model as a JSON. So I am not really using FK here. But I put it in parenthesis to show you what it is really.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select u.UserName, p.ProjectName
from user_project up
inner join user u on u.id = up.user_id
inner join project p on p.id = up.project_id
```

For each record in `user_project`, the query retrieves the name of the associated user and project in tables `user` and `project`. This is how I understood your question. I cannot see how table `AssignedProject` relates to the other tables.

Comment: yes exactly. I had almost the same thing. Yours works to select. Now my next question is inserting it into the user_project

Comment: Your original question was about selecting data, not inserting. Also I cannot se what to insert in `user_projects`, since this table has just 3 columns, that are already filled with data...

Comment: Yes, you are right. You've answered my question 100%. I was just wondering if you knew how to Insert.

Comment: @Mikeez: there is not enough information right now for me to answer on the `insert` query (to start with: in which table do you want to insert?). Generally speaking, you can turn a `select` to an insert query like: `insert into some_table select <the query>`. For something more specific, you could [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).